# How can I export a Seed Points layer as a image?

Tags: export, image, watershed

I have the Seed Points layer produced by Watershed Segmentation. I want to export is as a image (with background).

How can I do this?

I understand that I can do Project->Export->Export Map to Image.

However this takes the extent of the points layers, which might be smaller than the image to which the points have been put. When it should be the extent of the original image.

Answer (score 0):

The Export Map to Image dialog allows you to specify the extent of the image. You can choose extent of some layer you pick, the current canvas extent, or draw a rectanble on the current canvas. Sounds like you want the current canvas.

Comment: I also discovered the problem that the Export Map option seems to alter DPI somehow, the points come out as bigger or being slightly dislocated. How can I retain the seed points layer just as it's seen in QGIS?

Comment: The DPI is also specified in the export dialog. I've found the default value often to be quite strange.